# Add filter to Add existing button crm 2011

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

I followed the instructions in this link 
but I face a strange problem which is when the lookup is populated with the new filtered view the add button is getting disabled when I select a record from the new view !!
I debugged the code in the lookupinfo.aspx page and I found this line of code that controls whether the add button is enabled or disabled 
btnAdd.disabled = (crmGrid.InnerGrid.SelectedRecords.length == 0);
and this line of code always return true despite there is a selected record !!

Can anyone help me ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I followed the instructions in this link

Which link? I can't see one referenced in your question. I'll make some assumptions about what you are trying to do. I will assume that you are trying to hide an "Add Existing" button linked to a form's sub-grid. I'll also assuem you're trying to edit XML files by hand (which is the hard way!).

The easiest way to apply rules to buttons in CRM 2011 is to use Erik Pool's brilliant tool "Visual Ribbon Editor" (available [here)](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/)).

To hide an "Add Existing" button based on selected records, you would:

1. Connect the tool to your CRM environment
2. Open the "parent" entity (i.e. the record type that shows the "Add Existing xxxx" button
3. Select the Ribbon Type to be "Sub-Grid"
4. Select the button you wish to manipulate
5. Add or edit the Enable Rules for that button

If I'm not describing a solution to your problem, maybe enhance your question - it's hard to understand what you are trying to acheive.